# Can I ask this question differently without it getting closed?

Tags: discussion

The question [What is the best Canon lens (around $500) for taking pictures of my newborn?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/what-is-the-best-canon-lens-around-500-for-taking-pictures-of-my-newborn) 
The answers fulfill the posters original question OK I think. But for example the top answer recommends the 28mm f/2.8 lens, which in my opinion is not even close to a wide enough aperture for newborn photography.

Maybe **the entire difference between how I want to ask this question and how this was previously asked is price**. $500 is not even a ballpark figure for what I will spend on a lens. I want to get the best, ignoring price.

**Can I ask the exact same question and remove the price barrier?**

As a side note, the thread doesn't mention the 35mm f/1.4 L or 24 f/1.4 L, which are two HUGE reasons to even select full frame, and in my opinion may be the BEST newborn lenses available(I could be wrong, that is why I want to ask).

Comment: I do wonder why you hold that f/2.8 isn't wide enough. I've admittedly only photographed 2 newborns, but used a 2.8 both times and both worked out really well despite not using high speed film. No flash needed :)

Comment: At 28mm f/2.8 isn't going to give you a very narrow depth of field. Even on an APS-C sensor, I would recommend 50mm and up be used with f/2.8.

Comment: ah, 28. I used a 70

Answer (score 5):

Since the original question has an explicit budgetary requirement, asking something similar but with a higher or unlimited budgetary limit would be acceptable. However, to be honest, I think you particularly are probably quite capable of deciding for yourself, dpollitt. ;) You've already narrowed it down to two key options...the 35/1.4 and 24/1.4. You are skilled enough to know why those lenses could fit your need, and only you are capable of deciding what you really want to spend on such a lens. I'm not really sure asking a question here will give you any other insight you can't garner for yourself.

Comment: Unlimited budget, honestly.  Im hoping for other input as I'm no newborn expert are you?

Comment: @dpollitt: I'm not really sure there is such a thing as a "newborn expert". There may be people who are experts at portraiture, but I doubt there are many people who are specifically experts at newborn baby portraiture (although there are probably a few people who are). A lot of that is also feel and emotion, and a bit of personal style. So long as you have decent gear and are therefor released from having to worry about whether your equipment is satisfactory...I think its something that you can really feel your way through, using your existing knowledge of photography.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead, ask the question. Bring out the same motives and comparison to old question you mention here. Even if it does get closed (by community decision), there's still a good chance you'll get some valuable comments or answers.